# Sprinkler System Problems

Tags: sprinkler-system, irrigation

I have an Orbit Home B-Hyve wifi sprinker system, which has worked great for like 18 months.

However, three days ago it just stopped working completely. When I manually engage a zone from my phone, the controller says that it is running, yet no water is going to the valves. Every zone fails and has the same behavior.

I did check the voltage at each zone when it was turned off, and there was a voltage of around 16.8 VAC at each zone when touching the zone and common wire.

Here is where it gets odd, maybe.

I engaged zone 1, and check the terminal for 1 to COM, and get around 28 VAC.

With zone 1 still engaged, each of the other zones, 2 through 6 report a voltage of around 28 VAC also. Is this normal?

I also get an infinity reading of resistance when checking the zones to the COM.

What could be the problem? I am completely stumped!

Comment: No it’s not normal.  Since every valve has a coil there’s no chance for what’s known as “phantom voltage”.  If the readings are as you say they are, that controllers life is over.  Essentially all valves are turning on, and there isn’t enough current for the valves to actually open.  We don’t do product recommendations here, but unless it’s under warranty from orbitz and your getting another orbitz for free, I’d replace it with a Rachio controller.  Your valves are compatible.

Comment: So I called Orbit, and they said its normal for every station to put out the same 28VAC when a station is engaged???

Comment: Doesn’t make sense to me.